# Georeference toolbar in QGIS does not show up

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, georeferencing

I need to use Georeference toolbar and I searched for it under Raster tab, but it was not there. I searched for its plugin to install, but there is no Georeference plugin to install, instead there is this Freehand raster georeferencer plugin that I do not want.

[image]

I uninstalled my version and installed the QGIS version 3.30.2-'s-Hertogenbosch and I downloaded it using OSGeo4W installer. Still there is no plugin to install and it does not show up under Raster tab. How can I install the plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found it under the Layer tab. Apparently it has been moved there since version 3.26.

Comment: Moved there because from version 3.26, it can georeference vector layers as well, not just rasters. So it makes no sense to have it in menu raster.